# dsub: google cloud error ("exit status 141")

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-genomics

I was trying to run some whole genome sequencing samples on google cloud using dsub. The dsub commands work ok for some samples, but not others. I have tried reducing the number of parallel threads, increasing the memory and disk, but it still fails. Since each run takes about 2 days, the trial and error approach is pretty expensive! Any help/tips would be highly appreciated!

My command is:

```
dsub \    
  --project "${MY_PROJECT}" \
  --zones "us-central1-a" \
  --logging "${LOGGING}" \
  --vars-include-wildcards \
  --disk-size 800 \
  --min-ram 60 \
  --image "us.gcr.io/xxx-yyy-zzz/data" \
  --tasks "${SCRIPT_DIR}"/tBOWTIE2.tsv \
  --command 'bismark --bowtie2 --bam --parallel 2 "${GENOME_REFERENCE}" -1 "${INPUT_FORWARD}" -2 "${INPUT_REVERSE}" -o "${OUTPUT_DIR}"' \
  --wait
```

The dstat command with '--full' option shows the error as:

```
  status: FAILURE
  status-detail: "11: Docker run failed"
```

The last line in the log file, on google cloud, just states "(exit status 141)".

many thanks!

Comment: `exit status 141`  means http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lpg/node20.html

Comment: Have you tried Google Cloud Genomics Forum [link] (https://cloud.google.com/genomics/docs/support)